# Reading from file. Android, Java

Tags: java, android, file

I have some problem with reading file with Scanner.

My file has a following format:

line 1(basic signs, f.e.: ##%%&&).
line 2(number of lines with data, f.e.: 70)
line 3(some info)
line 4-74(some data in any format with semiColon as a delimiter)

I need to implement loop which started from fourth line and allows me to fill my ListView.
How to solve this problem?

here is part of code:

```
        Scanner read = null;
        Pattern b = Pattern.compile(";|\\|\n ");
        String BasicSign, NumberOfFields, barcode, name, type, amount, price;

        try {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG1, "--- Reading from spr: ---");
            File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File textFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "myFile1.spr");

            read = new Scanner(textFile);
            read.useDelimiter(b);
            while (read.hasNext()) {
                BasicSign = read.next();
                NumberOfFields = read.next();
                barcode = read.next();
                name = read.next();
                amount = read.next();
                price = read.next();

                tvBarcode.setText(barcode123);
                tvMyName.setText(name);
                tvType.setText(type);
                tvPrice.setText(price);
            }
            read.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: Why not tu use [BufferReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and use a counter for check the line number?

Answer (score 0):

You could process your textfile linewise and skip the first 3 lines and start in the 4th. This is a simple straight forward solution:

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(textfile);
        br.readLine(); // skip line
        br.readLine(); // skip line
        br.readLine(); // skip line

        String line = br.readLine(); // start in 4th line
        while (line !=null) { // end of file not reached
            Scanner read = new Scanner(line);
            read.useDelimiter(b);
            //your while loop and processing
            line = br.readLine(); // read line for next iteration
        }
        br.close();
```